# VBA: copying the first empty cell in the same row

Tags: vba, excel

I am a new user of VBA and am trying to do the following (I got stuck towards the end):

I need to locate the first empty cell across every row from column C to P (3 to 16), take this value, and paste it in the column B of the same row.

What I try to do was:

1. Find non-empty cells in column C, copy those values into column B.
2. Then search for empty cells in column B, and try to copy the first non-empty cell in that row.

The first part worked out fine, but I am not too sure how to copy the first non-empty cell in the same row. I think if this can be done, I might not need the first step. Would appreciate any advice/help on this. There is the code:

```
Private Sub Test()

For j = 3 To 16
For i = 2 To 186313
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then
        Cells(i, j - 1) = Cells(i, j)

            End If
sourceCol = 2

'column b has a value of 2
RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for every row, find the first blank cell, copy the first not empty value in that row
For currentRow = 1 To RowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) Or Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) Or Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5)) Or Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6)) Then
    Paste

~ got stuck here

        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by " first empty cell across every row from column C to P (3 to 16)," when you reach an empty cell take the value from the previous column or the cloumn afterwards or...???


As I understood it you want to do the following: Loop through col B, when the row is empty search col C to P take the first value of these columns and paste it to B correct?

Comment: Hi psychicebola, that's right! (Loop through col B, when the row is empty search col C to P take the first value of these columns and paste it to B correct?) . Sorry if I wasn't clear enough on that, CBRF23 has also helped with this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is really inefficient as it is iterating over millions of cells, most of which don't need looked at.  `(16-3)*(186313-2)=2,422,043`.

I also don't recommend using `xlUp` or `xlDown` or `xlCellTypeLastCell` as these don't always return the results you expect as the meta-data for these cells are created when the file is saved, so any changes you make after the file is saved but before it is re-saved can give you the wrong cells. This can make debugging a nightmare.  Instead, I recommend using the [`Find()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method to find the last cell.  This is fast and reliable.

Here is how I would probably do it.  I'm looping over the minimum amount of cells I can here, which will speed things up.

You may also want to disable the `screenupdating` property of the application to speed things up and make the whole thing appear more seemless.

Lastly, if you're new to VBA it's good to get in the  habit of disabling the `enableevents` property as well so if you currently have, or add in the future, any event listeners you will not trigger the procedures associated with them to run unnecessarily or even undesirably.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Dim LastUsed As Range
    Dim PasteHere As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating=False
    Application.EnableEvents=False

    With Range("B:B")
        Set PasteHere = .Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, False, False)
        If PasteHere Is Nothing Then Set PasteHere = .Cells(1, 1) Else: Set PasteHere = PasteHere.Offset(1)
    End With
    For i = 3 To 16
        Set LastUsed = Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Find("*", Cells(1, i), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False, False, False)
        If Not LastUsed Is Nothing Then
            LastUsed.Copy Destination:=PasteHere
            Set PasteHere = PasteHere.Offset(1)
        End If
        Set LastUsed = Nothing
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating=True
    Application.EnableEvents=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi CBRF23, thank you for your explanation on the syntax, the screenupdating and enableevents and the code!

Comment: @TiffanyTang on this site up voting is the proper way to thank someone for a helpful post; you do this by simply clicking the "up" arrow next to the answer (or comment).  If I've answered your question, please click the empty checkbox next to my answer to make it green.  This will let others know your question has been resolved, so they do not need to spend time on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub non_empty()
Dim lstrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lstrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lstrow
   If IsEmpty(Range("B" & i)) Then
      Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).End(xlToRight).Value
   End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nitish, thank you! It worked, however, the search didn't end at column p. It went on researching for the first non empty cell in that row and copied the value.

Comment: Hi Tiffany, you want to search through entire row or you need to fill the gap with first col which has value

Comment: Hi Nitish, I would like to search the from column c - p in a row and fill the gap with the first col that has value.

Comment: Hi Tiffany, as per my understanding you want to search through column B for the empty cell. If empty cell found you have to take a value from Columns C to P which cell has the value. Is that right or do you have a different requirement.

Comment: Hi Nitish, yup that is right. The code above searches through all columns. The one which CBFR23 provided work well too!

Comment: @TiffanyTang - just curious, why did you change the marked answer to this post if it is not working for you?